# PHPExcel: How to get a CELL COLOR

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel project, but I am having a question in mind, and without solution on the earth.

I had googled for this question for a while, but I CAN NOT find a way to get a CELL BACKGROUND COLOR!

I tried to use the method 'getColor()' or what ... it doesn't work or just shows the warning message...

Can somebody please tell me how to get a CELL COLOR using PHPExcel? THANKS

Comment: What warning message does it show?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFill()->getStartColor()->getARGB();
```

or

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFill()->getStartColor()->getRGB();
```

Comment: This does not work when `$objPHPExcel->setReadDataOnly(true);` and it would always return `FFFFFF` whatever color it has.

Comment: @Sithu - yes, if you explicitly tell PHPExcel not to read the style information, then you won't be able to get that information subsequently.... that seems pretty logical to me

Comment: @Sithu thank you! your comment should be more visible for others having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

examples<
http://bayu.freelancer.web.id/2010/07/16/phpexcel-advanced-read-write-excel-made-simple/

Answer (score 0):

to set background for specific cells.it's works for me

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,'startcolor' => array('rgb' =>'FF1E1E')
```